# Como fazer overload de um construtor e também chamar o construtor da classe base em C#?

Tags: c#, construtor, sobrecarga

Estou criando um erro em C# que deve estender a classe `Exception` mas, também deve acrescer uma propriedade extra, assim:

```cs
public class CampoVazioErro: Exception
{
    public string campo { get; }

        public CampoVazioErro(object c)
        {
            campo = c;
        }
        public CampoVazioErro(object c, string m) : base(m)
        {
        }
        public CampoVazioErro(object c, string m, Exception i) : base(m, i)
        {
        }
}
```

É possível eu chamar o construtor da classe base `Exception` e também chamar o construtor mais simples da minha classe `CampoVazioErro(object c)`? Ao meu entender deve existir alguma forma de fazer isso mas não estou achando na internet.

> **Nota:** eu sei que para chamar outro construtor dentro da mesma classe eu só tenho que passar o `this()` na frente de outro construtor (ex: `CampoVazioErro(object c, string m): this(c)` mas não faço a mínima ideia de como chamar isso e também o construtor da minha superclasse.

Comment: Você teria que chamar o construtor "simples" da sua classe com o `: this(c)` e então o construtor simples teria a chamada pro construtor base usando o `: base()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes de exceção deveriam sempre terminar com a palavra `Exception`. Você deveria herdar de [`ApplicationException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.applicationexception?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) e não `Exception`. Na verdade esta última deveria ser esquecida por desenvolvedores em geral. E até por isto considero a terceira assinatura um erro.

De forma geral não deveria usar `object` como tipo de nada. Isto é praticamente um legado da linguagem.

Esses construtores não possuem relação direta com os construtores base. Só alertando se achar que tem, as assinaturas não diferentes.

```
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        try {
            throw new CampoVazioException<int>(1);
        } catch (CampoVazioException<int>) {
            Console.WriteLine("deu erro");
        }
    }
}

public class CampoVazioException<T>: ApplicationException {
    public T Objeto { get; }

    public CampoVazioException(T objeto) : this(objeto, "") {}
    public CampoVazioException(T objeto, string mensagem) : base(mensagem) {
        Objeto = objeto;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UwC5Pe). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NQN3Zj). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/EmptyField.cs).

Comment: Maniero, quando você fala sobre a classe `Exception`, dizendo que `deveria ser esquecida por desenvolvedores em geral`. Qual o motivo? Há alguma referência que você poderia adicionar sobre o assunto?

Comment: Ela até pode ser útil aqui e ali, mas as pessoas usam ela como uma forma preguiçosa de lançar exceção. Se for para fazer assim é melhor nem usar exceção. Um dos motivos principais que a exceção foi criada é dar muita informação sobre o erro, e principalmente qual é o erro. Toda vez que alguém lança ou captura uma exceção está fazendo usando exceção do jeito errado (exceto pelas exceções desta regra, eu não resisto aos trocadilhos :) ). Algumas pessoas dizem até que esta, e mesmo a `ApplicationException` e algumas outras exceções de "alto nível" deveriam ser abstratas e não permitir herança.

Comment: Esta classe foi criada para dar a infraestrutura geral de exceções, não para os desenvolvedores usarem diretamente. Em alguns casos a captura dela é útil, em geral perto do ponto de entrada da aplicação, quando tudo mais falhou e vai *logar* o erro antes da aplicação quebrar.

Comment: Bastante esclarecedor. É uma filosofia/boa prática que direnciona para um _clean code_. Obrigado!

Comment: Sobre a nomenclatura de classes, não concordo com a afirmação, visto que não é uma obrigação da linguagem mas somente uma boa prática no geral. Sobre a classe `ApplicationException`, irei começar a usá-la pois concordo com o conceito.